# Openshift 3.X - communication between backend and frontend

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openshift

I've two docker images, one is a webserver and the other is a backend Rest application. I deployed those images in an Openshift cluster. I want to configure my pods where the webserver is running to access the pods where the backend Rest application is running but I can't figure out how I can specify to my front-end pods that they have to communicate with my back-end service. I can only reach the pod ip but that's not what I want as I want to keep scalability advantage.

I tried to access it like this:

1. via a defined route: svc-backend.router.default.svc.cluster.local
2. via his service name: svc-backend.environment.svc.cluster.local
3. via his ip adress (internal): 172.30.214.192
4. via master host + service name: master.svc-backend.environment.svc.cluster.local

Nothing worked sadly. Can anyone explain to me how to communicate in openshift between pods and services?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is deploy those 2 pods in the same project so you can keep the communication internally:

```
$ oc new-project test
$ oc new-app registry:5000/frontend-image
$ oc new-app registry:5000/backend-image
```

This will automatically create a deploymentconfig and create your pod + container + a replication controller (for high availability, it will check if the pod is still running) + a service.

A service is an important aspect. This is actually a loadbalancer which will distribute the traffic between multiple pods. The `oc new-app` will check which ports are exposed an create a service above the ports.
So for example you can scale up your frontend pod to 3, than the service will distribute visitor1 to pod1 and another visitor to pod2 etc. A service is stable so its IP will not change. A service IP starts with 172.30.xx.xx.  So traffic sended to this IP will be forwarded to your pod(s). So for save internal network it's the best to connect services. You can connect to the service name which will be translated to the service IP. (If there is some weird case that you have to recreate your service you can create it with the same name so you don't have to change your appconfigs).

E.g.
I have an application which is connected with a mysql database.
In the conf of my application I'm pointing to connect with host: mysql. This is the name of the service of my MySQL.

```
             connection: {
                 host: 'mysql',
                 user: 'xx-user',
                 password: 'xx',
                 database: 'db',
charset: 'utf8'
```

You can check your service:

```
$ oc get svc
```

or in the webconsole

[image]

So for your application you have to point to the service-name of your backend. (I first have to start the database because otherwise the deployment of my app will fail because it would not find the database). So you first have to deploy your backend + create the service and point to that service name in the config of your frontend.

Sometimes you aren't able to keep everything internally. Than you have to create routes on your services. This will expose your service to the outside and you can communicate over routes. 
Than you have to point to those routes in your configs. The routes will be translated by the OpenShift router and the router will forward it to the right service.
Give some feedback if things aren't clear.

**EDIT 1:**

```
nslookup mysql                                                          
Server:         172.30.0.1                                                      
Address:        172.30.0.1#53                                                   

Name:   mysql.test.svc.cluster.local                                       
Address: 172.30.195.xx
```

**EDIT 2:**
Start mysql in OpenShift (use ephemeral template: user=test, password=test, database=test.
Go inside your container and try to authenticate in the following way:
You'll define your user, password and host (host = servicename). This will also work with your service IP: 172.30.xxx)

```
sh-4.2$ mysql -utest -ptest -hmysql                                     
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.        
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.                       
Your MySQL connection id is 48880                                               
Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)                             

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.    

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its               
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective                   
owners.                                                                         

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.  

mysql>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. That's also what I thought but when I try from one pod to access the other one with service name or ip I always get a no route to host error: wget http://backend:8080/           
--2016-07-29 09:35:22--  http://backend:8080/                                                                               
Resolving backend (backend)... 172.30.148.197                         
Connecting to backend (backend)|172.30.148.197|:8080... failed: No route to host.

Comment: Oh that's so nice thanks a lot it's not easy to understand all the mechanisms this is a pretty complicated product and I'm stuck since a while on this communication problem :)

Comment: what happend when you try to ping your services (so from frontend ping the servicename frontend and ping the servicename backend: normally the icmp port is closed on your container but it must be able to resolve your servicename to an ip: So I ping mysql ---> PING mysql.dev-proj.svc.cluster.local (172.30.137.144): 56 data bytes       
92 bytes from 10.1.2.1: Destination Host Unreachable (it resolves my service name mysql to the service IP) (ping from inside your container ofcourse)

Comment: I've the same behavior: 
PING backend.development.svc.cluster.local (172.30.148.197) 56(84) bytes of
 data.                                                                          
From gateway (10.128.1.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: I see two things. First I've a Kubernetes service in my default project who has no pod started (don't know if it's normal). Secondly my frontend-service just disappear, I got only the pod running now and I had a route on this one but not on the backend.

Comment: That's normal there isn't a kubernetes pod. It's just a service. Wel that's fine so your pod is already able to connect to the service ofyour other pod (backend) so you're able to use the service name in your configs. Can you explain your second issue? I'll recommend to create a route on your service of the frontend. And in the config of your frontend you have to point to the name of the service of your backend (which is in the same project). Than recreate image/push and build. Normally a service does not dissapear?

Comment: The service does not dissapear but you don't see it directly in your webconsole (than you see the route). Perform this in the project in your shell: oc get svc (than you have to see 2 services)

Comment: To check if it's working you can also curl instead of using the route (routing needs wildcard dns mapped on the ip of the node where your router is running). So to check without a route you can curl inside your node-server to svc-ip:port (of your frontend). Than you'll see your frontend an hopefully see the information provided by your backend. (normally you were linking front and backend with an IP I assume (inconfigs), now you have to use service-names).

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers, I try to figure out what I can do wrong but it ain't easy. Now I start thinking that I have problem with my internal networking. I tried to deploy a standalone mysql image and get this error in pod creation: failed to setup network for pod using network plugins openshift-ovs-subnet. Do you have any idea how I can check if my internal network is correctly settup?

Comment: I'm on an openshift version < 1.3.0 (origin). Than it's normal these logs shows up. You can always check if everything is right by starting your mysql. and going inside the container on the webconsole (terminal) and try to login on your mysql using its service name: mysql -uyouruser -pyourpassword -hmysql (service name)

Comment: I upgraded to 1.3.0 but now I get an unknown manifest error... Probably due to the docker schema bug between version 1.9 and 1.10... My big problem is that I can't use any services ip addresses, I can only communicate between pods using the container ip address. Even when I'm inside a pod from a service I can't ping or curl the service ip address. Therefore I think more and more that there's some communication problem inside my openshift installation but I've no idea how to find why or what's wrong... Always become failed: no route to host as soon as I use an SVC name or address.

Comment: Are you able to perform an nslookup on a servicename in a container? Than you can see if your installation is using the right DNS server (must be the internal dns of OpenShift). I've edited my answer. so I performed an nslookup inside my mysql container of the mysql-service above

Comment: Ok thank you I'm using my DNS and not the one from openshift: Server: 10.1.1.19, Address: 10.1.1.19#53, Name backend.development.svc.cluster.local, Address: 172.30.193.133. Is it a problem as it still can resolve the name?

Comment: Hmm don't think so when it's able to resolve. I had it once too using my own dns but there it was a problem. Is there something like this in your node-config.yaml or master-config.yaml: dnsIP: 10.1.1.19

Comment: But I see you said "I've the same behavior: PING backend.development.svc.cluster.local (172.30.148.197) 56(84) bytes of data. From gateway (10.128.1.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable " So you are able to ping your service (it's just because your icmp port is closed probably that the host is unreachable) but your should be able to communicatie with the pod inside your service.

Comment: Actually my problem is the routing inside openshift. I can resolve the Service names from the pods to the correct ip addresses but I've not idea how to route my request from the 10.128.0.0/16 network (pods network) to the 172.30.0.0/16 network (service network). So either the pods have a wrong router configuration or the router in openshift himself don't know the other networks. Do you have any idea how to debug those kind of problem or just how it is supposed to work inside openshift?

Comment: for the node-config.yaml I've actually the entry dnsIP: 10.1.1.19 and in the master for the dns-config I've 0.0.0.0:8053.

Comment: Can you maybe show the logs of your router (+ did you succeed with the mysql example?)

Comment: For the mysql example, since I updated to version 1.3.0 I got an unknown manifest error when trying to download the image. Here are the log from the router: 
I0803 09:14:44.622788       1 router.go:310] Router reloaded:
 - Checking HAProxy /healthz on port 1936 ...
 - HAProxy port 1936 health check ok : 0 retry attempt(s).
I0803 09:24:38.727335       1 router.go:310] Router reloaded:
 - Checking HAProxy /healthz on port 1936 ...
 - HAProxy port 1936 health check ok : 0 retry attempt(s).
...

Comment: Oh I found out something really interesting: in my default project I have an application deployed who is accessible by is services. in my development project I've two apps who are not accessible. When I do oc get endpoints on the default project they have all endpoints addresses but in my development project they have none: 
oc get endpoints
NAME            ENDPOINTS   AGE
backend    <none>      4d
frontend   <none>      4d

Comment: I will open a new question as this discussion come a little too messy. I'm really happy with your answer it's even perfect :) Thank you so much and sadly I can't validate the answer but consider it as resolved.